# ¿Cuales son los numeros de grupos en esta expresión regular y como identificarlos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular para encontrar numeros telefonicos:

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'(' '\n'
                    r'    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                  # código de area' '\n'
                    r'    (\s|-|\.)?                          # separador' '\n'
                    r'    (\d{3})                             # primeros 3 digitos' '\n'
                    r'    (\s|-|\.)                           # separador' '\n'
                    r'    (\d{4})                             # últimos 4 digitos' '\n'
                    r'    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?      # extensión ' '\n'
                    r'    )', re.VERBOSE)
```

Necesito identificar cuantos grupos hay y cuales son.

Comment: y los paréntesis que están dentro de un paréntesis cuentan?

Comment: He convertido en respuesta mis anteriores comentarios, para darle más visibilidad, por si es de utilidad a alguien más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada vez que encierras algo entre paréntesis en la expresión regular (a menos que los paréntesis estén "escapados" con un `\`), estás creando un grupo.

Los grupos pueden crearse por dos razones:

1. Para "agrupar" (valga la redundancia), y así marcar el grupo entero como opcional, o con un número dado de repeticiones, etc. Por ejemplo, en tu expresión tienes `(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?`. Los paréntesis más exteriores delimitan un grupo que está formado por un número (quizás cero) de espacios, una de las cadenas "ext", "x" o "ext." (cuidado que el punto final representa cualquier carácter), otra secuencia de (quizás cero) espacios, y un entre 2 y 5 dígitos. El grupo completo lleva un `?` al final que indica que todo el conjunto es opcional.
2. Para "capturar" lo que has encerrado entre paréntesis y poder acceder a ello, separado del resto, o poder usarlo como parte de un patrón de sustitución.

Sea cual sea la causa, cada trozo entre paréntesis da lugar a un grupo. Si están anidados también (los grupos se van creando en el orden en que se abren los paréntesis).

Si dentro del grupo los primeros caracteres son `?:`, eso indica que el grupo es de "no-captura". Se trata de grupos que cumplen la función 1, pero no la 2, porque no estamos interesados en lo que contienen como grupo, sólo en su existencia como parte de la validación.

Por tanto en tu expresión regular hay 9 grupos:

1. El global, pues toda la expresión la tienes entre paréntesis
2. El código de área, que son 3 dígitos o bien 3 dígitos entre paréntesis (estos están "escapados" para marcar que nos referimos a paréntesis en la cadena a buscar, y no en grupos de la expresión regular)
3. El separador que puede ser un espacio, un guión o un punto
4. Tres dígitos
5. Otro separador
6. Cuatro dígitos
7. El código de extensión que se compone de un número variable (quizás cero) de espacios separando más grupos:
8. La cadena "x" o "ext" o "ext."
9. Un grupo de entre 2 y 5 dígitos

Para ayudarte a entender todo esto puedes usar python:

```
>>> phoneRegex.groups
9
>>> r = phoneRegex.match("(111)-333.4444 x 6666")
>>> r.groups()
('(111)-333.4444 x 6666', '(111)', '-', '333', '.', '4444', ' x 6666', 'x', '6666')
```

Sospecho que parte de estos grupos no necesitaban ser de captura. Por ejemplo ¿necesitamos saber si los separadores eran puntos o guiones? Probablemente no. ¿Necesitamos saber la sintaxis `"x 6666" de la extensión, y si se usó la abreviatura "x" o "ext", o basta con el número de extensión? Supongo que lo segundo.

Por tanto podríamos marcar como de "no captura" los grupos en los que no estemos interesados, así:

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'(' '\n'
                    r'    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                  # código de area' '\n'
                    r'    (?:\s|-|\.)?                          # separador' '\n'
                    r'    (\d{3})                             # primeros 3 digitos' '\n'
                    r'    (?:\s|-|\.)                           # separador' '\n'
                    r'    (\d{4})                             # últimos 4 digitos' '\n'
                    r'    (?:\s*(?:ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?      # extensión ' '\n'
                    r'    )', re.VERBOSE)
```

En esta ocasión sólo tenemos 5 grupos de captura, con la parte relevante (los dígitos), más el global que captura la expresión completa por si la necesitamos.

```
>>> phoneRegex.groups
5
>>> r = phoneRegex.match("(111)-333.4444 x 6666")
>>> r.groups()
('(111)-333.4444 x 6666', '(111)', '333', '4444', '6666')
```